# foundation.css init by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, bower

I compile all my bower's scss at bower.css, but I am still seeing foundation.css and other css from my bower_components in my developer tool(see img).  I clear my cache/history restarted my computer but it is still there.  this is a very simple .php with only 100 lines, and there is no other `js` or `link` in the document.

fig 1

[image: foundation.css init as line 78]

it said foundation.css is init at line 78 in index.php

[image: jquery cdn]

but my line 78 is my cdn to jquery source,  so how do that file get there?

and just a side question, I am only using the grid, so I don't need to init  `$(document).foundation();` right ?

Comment: Can you try to copy/paste some of your index.php code around line 78?

Comment: thanks, I found out what my problem is, @import in bower.sass, translate directly as @ import, instead of compile everything in one. thanks anyway.